# Type inference in Kotlin lambdas fails when using `it` special variable

Tags: kotlin, lambda, type-inference

I fail to understand, why the following compiles:

```
directory.listFiles { it -> it.name.startsWith("abc") }
```

but this doesn't:

```
directory.listFiles { it.name.startsWith("abc") }
```

Am I correctly assuming that in the first case, the type of `it` is inferred via the `name` property? Why is this not happening in the second case?

Answer (score 1):

It is because there are two possible `FunctionalInterfaces` that can be used with `File.listFiles`:

1. `listFiles(FileFilter)` - this interface is `accept(File pathname)`
2. `listFiles(FilenameFilter)` - this interface is `accept​(File dir, String name)`

The compiler cannot work out which you want to use.  So how is this better in the case you write `it ->`?

Well, the compiler inspects the call arguments of the two interface methods and can now see you expect one argument "`SOMETHING ->`," so the only matching call is the `FileFilter` variation.

How might you use the `FilenameFilter`?  you'd use this syntax:

```
directory.listFiles { dir, name -> name.startsWith("abc") }
```

The magic here is not `it` - that's a coincidence, but that you declared just **one** parameter.

Comment: I understand, but this means my assumption is wrong, that using the special variable `it` would imply only single parameter? How could using `it` possibly refer to a functional interface with more than one parameter? That's what is confusing me.

Comment: @ThomasHirsch I think it is probably just a limitation of the compiler. Leaving no named parameter means you have either 0 or 1 parameter, so it is sort of ambiguous until you look at all the possible numbers of parameters in overloads of the function. Maybe the compiler doesn't take that extra step.

Comment: Note that `it` is not a keyword in the same way as `class` or `in`, which are _always_ interpreted as keywords, and can't be used any other way (except by quoting in backquotes); it's more like a soft keyword like `by` and `init`, which act as keywords only in certain contexts.  (In fact, the docs describe it as a ‘special identifier’, not as a keyword at all.)